# Use of undeclared identifier 'self'. When I try to use [self presentViewController] in functions

Tags: ios, objective-c

Use of undeclared identifier 'self. I got this error while trying to run [self presentViewController... in function which I created. But it works if I try to run this in the action of a button.

```
     void showAlert() 
        {
            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Button" style:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
       }];

         [alert addAction:button];        
         [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix Swift and objective c it should be

```
-(void) showAlert {

      UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

      UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Button" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
      }];

   [alert addAction:button];
   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also it's `UIAlertActionStyleDefault`not `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`